# Python pydobc SQL ODBC Microsoft Access Drive Too few parameters

Tags: sql, python-2.7, ms-access, pyodbc

Trying to obtain filtered results matching TableA and a TableB with both a column col1 and WHERE a python variable "Bingo" NOT IN TableB col3

```
 bingo = 'Data1'
 SQL = 'SELECT a.* FROM TABLEA a WHERE a.col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM TABLEB) AND (?) NOT IN (SELECT col3 FROM TABLEB);'
 rows = cur.execute(SQL,bingo).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the name of the field. You are better off using Python's substitutions/formatting with [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) such as this:

```
bingo = 'Data1'
SQL = 'SELECT a.* FROM TABLEA a WHERE a.col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM TABLEB) AND {} NOT IN (SELECT col3 FROM TABLEB);'.format(bingo)
rows = cur.execute(SQL).fetchall()
```